A variant of ultrametric space
It is well-known that $(X, d)$ is called an ultrametric space if we repalce the usual triangle inequality with the strong ultrametric triangle inequality : $d(x,y)\le \max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}$ for any $x,y,z\in X$. Now,  we replace the ultrametric triangle inequality by
$$d(x,y)\le \beta\max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}$$
for some $\beta>0$. Of course, if $\beta\le 1$ then the above ultrametric triangle inequality still holds and the space $(X,d)$ is an ultrametric space. My question is : Is it meaningful to sudy such space in the case $\beta>1?$  This question is movitated by the paper "Regularity of Multivariate Refinable Functions, Constr. Approx. (1999) 15: 241–255". In this paper, a  “pseudo-norm" was introduced and the "metric" induced by it satisfies the above inequality and we don't know whether $\beta\le 1$.

It's maybe worth noting that $\beta \geq 2$ gives a weaker version of the usual triangle inequality.

If we still have $d(y,y) = 0$ for all $y$, and if there are $x, y$ with $d(x, y) > 0$, then we can't have $\beta < 1$.  To see this, observe that the inequality applied with $z=y$ gives $d(x, y) \leq \beta \max{d(x,y), d(y,y)} = \beta d(x,y)$, and this can't occur if $\beta < 1$ and $d(x, y) > 0$.  So your $\beta \leq 1$ case is really the $\beta = 1$ case.  I don't have any insight into the $\beta > 1$ case you asked about.

Would this give a topology at all?
